# Using a custom WindowFn on google dataflow which closes after an element value

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I extended a custom windowing function based on the apache beam Sessions window which starts a new user session if a maximum time gap has past or if a specific user event occurred, following the suggestions in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43035302/close-window-after-based-on-element-value/43052779#43052779).

Basically I added this IntervalWindow class:

```
class StoppingIntervalWindow(IntervalWindow):
    def __init__(self, start, end, event):
        super(StoppingIntervalWindow, self).__init__(start, end)
        self.event = event
```

Then I created a custom window by extending the WindowFn class.
I assign the window to the StoppingIntervalWindow and merging is done in a similar way as in the Session window:

```
class CustomWindow(WindowFn):

    def __init__(self, gap_size):
        if gap_size <= 0:
            raise ValueError('The size parameter must be strictly positive.')
        self.gap_size = Duration.of(gap_size)

    def assign(self, context):
        timestamp = context.timestamp
        event = context.element[1]["event"]
        return [StoppingIntervalWindow(timestamp, timestamp + self.gap_size, event)]

    def merge(self, merge_context):
        to_merge = []
        end = MIN_TIMESTAMP
        for w in sorted(merge_context.windows, key=lambda w: w.start):
            if to_merge:
                if w.event == 'stopping_event' or end <= w.start:
                    if len(to_merge) > 1:
                        merge_context.merge(to_merge, StoppingIntervalWindow(to_merge[0].start, end, to_merge[0].event))
                    to_merge = [w]
                    end = w.end
                else:
                    to_merge.append(w)
                    if w.end > end:
                        end = w.end
            else:
                to_merge = [w]
                end = w.end
        if len(to_merge) > 1:
            merge_context.merge(to_merge, StoppingIntervalWindow(to_merge[0].start, end, to_merge[0].event))

    def get_window_coder(self):
        return coders.IntervalWindowCoder()

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if type(self) == type(other) == CustomWindow:
            return self.gap_size == other.gap_size
```

My current problem is the following: Locally user data is aggregated correctly and different sessions are started every time an event occurs or a time gap has past. Once I run my code remotely in google cloud dataflow however, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 582, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 167, in execute
    op.start()
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 49, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
    def start(self):
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 50, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
    with self.scoped_start_state:
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 65, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
    with self.shuffle_source.reader() as reader:
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 69, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start
    self.output(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 154, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output
    cython.cast(Receiver, self.receivers[output_index]).receive(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 86, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive
    cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value)
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 232, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowsOperation.process
    for wvalue in self.driver.process_elements(state, vs, MIN_TIMESTAMP):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/transforms/trigger.py", line 993, in process_elements
    self.window_fn.merge(TriggerMergeContext(all_windows))
  File "/vagrant/adjust/session.py", line 50, in merge
AttributeError: 'IntervalWindow' object has no attribute 'event'
```

- Is there any way that I can use a custom IntervalWindow on Google Dataflow?
- If not, is there any other way to implement this use case for it to also work on Google Dataflow?

Comment: Could you share more of your code? I could not make the connection between how you are using the new logic within the context of the new StopIntervalWindow class.

In general, you can create custom windowing functions (similar to Sessions) by subclassing from WindowFn. Have you tried that?

Comment: @szere I added the complete code for the WindowFn. Once I try to use the window in a pipeline on dataflow I get the error above.